# Как сделать чтобы функция возвращала массив структур, память на который была выделена динамически?

Tags: c++, функции, struct

````
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct scan_info
{
    char model[25]; //найменування моделі
    int price;      // ціна
    double x_size;  // горизонтальний розмір області сканування
    double y_size;  // вертикальний розміробласті сканування
    int optr;       // оптичний дозвіл
    int grey;       // число градацій сірого
};

scan_info data_entry(); //

int main()
{
    data_entry();

    cout << data_array[1].model;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

scan_info data_entry()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Введіть кількість сканерів: ";
    cin >> number;
    scan_info *data_array;
    data_array = new scan_info[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << endl
             << "Сканер №" << i + 1 << endl;
        cout << "Введіть назву моделі: ";
        cin >> data_array[i].model;
        cout << "Ціна: ";
        cin >> data_array[i].price;
        cout << "Горизонтальний розмір області сканування: ";
        cin >> data_array[i].x_size;
        cout << "Вертикальний розміробласті сканування: ";
        cin >> data_array[i].y_size;
        cout << "Оптичний дозвіл: ";
        cin >> data_array[i].optr;
        cout << "Число градацій сірого: ";
        cin >> data_array[i].grey;
    }
    return data_array;
} ```
С этим массивом ещё нужно будет работать (выводить в файл и другое)
````

Comment: Возвращать надо указатель `scan_info * data_entry()`. А вообще, в C++ лучше работать с векторами, например...

Answer (score 0):

Функция должна быть:

```
        scan_info* data_entry(int& number)
{
  //int number;
  cout << "Введіть кількість сканерів: ";
    cin >> number;
...
  return data_array;
}
```

Необходимо возвратить количество элементов в массиве, не только указатель на массив.